How to stop landscape mode rotating screen by 90 degrees in swiftui
I am fairly new to coding , but managed to put together a camera app, based on snippets I've found on line.
I have a viewer with controls at the botttom of the screen when in portrait mode
The problem I have is that when I change the screen to landscape it rotates the image 90 degrees to the right instead of going widescreen and pushes the controls so far to the bottom of the screen they are not visibel.
What Id like to happen is for the viewer to go widscreen, but the controls stay to the right of viewer just like it does with the iphone camera.
Any help would be appreciated as this is all new to me.
TIA
I've looked at at several tutorials, and tried to read up on it,, but really struggled.
The code consists of a cameracontroller. a Camerapreview and a viewer for the actual camera image it self.
I'm happy and will to send all the code but don not want to break any rules,I will firstly send the viewer and preview
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    class VideoPreviewView: UIView {
        override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
            AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
        }
        
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
            return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        }
    }
    
    let session: AVCaptureSession
    @Binding var zoomFactor: CGFloat

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> VideoPreviewView {
        let view = VideoPreviewView()
        view.videoPreviewLayer.session = session
        view.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handlePinch(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: VideoPreviewView, context: Context) {
        // Update zoom factor when it changes
        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.videoZoomFactor = zoomFactor
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Error locking configuration for zoom: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: CameraPreview

        init(_ parent: CameraPreview) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        @objc func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
            if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) {
                let newZoomFactor = min(max(gesture.scale, 1.0), device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)
                if gesture.state == .changed {
                    parent.zoomFactor = newZoomFactor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AVKit


struct CoachCamView: View {
    @StateObject private var cameraController = CameraController()
    @State private var delayDuration: Double = 3.0
    @State private var recordingDuration: Double = 3.0
    @State private var showPlayback: Bool = false
    @State private var zoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Camera preview with zoom functionality
            if let session = cameraController.captureSession {
                CameraPreview(session: session, zoomFactor: $zoomFactor)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(height: 400)
                    .clipped()
            } else {
                Text("Setting up camera...")
                    .frame(height: 300)
            }

            // Slider for delay duration
            HStack {
                Text("Countdown:")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(width: 100.0)
                                Text("\(Int(delayDuration)) secs")
                
                Slider(value: $delayDuration, in: 3...10, step: 1) {
                    Text("Countdown")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                .frame(width: 150)
            }
            
            // Slider for recording duration
            HStack {
                Text("Duration: ")
                    .padding(.trailing, 15.0)
                    .frame(width: 100)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                              Text("\(Int(recordingDuration)) secs")
                
                Slider(value: $recordingDuration, in: 3...10, step: 1) {
                    Text("Duration")
                }
                .frame(width: 150)
            }
            
            HStack {
                // Start recording button
                Button(action: {
                    let delay = delayDuration
                    let duration = recordingDuration
                    let url = getRecordingURL()
                    print("Starting recording after \(delay) seconds delay")
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                        print("Starting recording")
                        cameraController.startRecording(to: url, duration: duration)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Start")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .padding(.all, 10.0)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 50.0)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                

                
                // Playback button
                Button(action: {
                    if let url = cameraController.lastRecordedVideoURL {
                        showPlayback = true
                        playVideo(url: url)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Play Last Recording")
                }
                .padding()
                .disabled(cameraController.lastRecordedVideoURL == nil)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 50.0)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                
                
                
                
            }


            
        }
        .onAppear {
            cameraController.setupSession()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPlayback) {
            VideoPlayerView(url: cameraController.lastRecordedVideoURL!)
        }
    }

    private func getRecordingURL() -> URL {
        let fileName = "output_\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).mov"
        let directory = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
        return directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }

    private func playVideo(url: URL) {
        // This function will be used to start video playback
        // It's used when showing the video player sheet
    }
}
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let url: URL

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

#Preview {
    CoachCamView()
}


